# Spring boot application stuck when adding jnpclient maven dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, jboss, jndi

I need to load a JNDI resource located in a JBoss server. For this, I am using a jnp-client library:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jboss</groupId>
  <artifactId>jnp-client</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

The problem is that as soon as I include this dependency in my pom.xml, the Spring application gets stuck at the start time without any message. Not a single line of logs, like if it is trying to load something forever. The main is not even invoked. Removing this dependency the application runs but I get an expected:

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
```

Which is normal because I have removed the dependency that includes this class.

Any clue?
I have tried all version of jnp-client or jbossall-client that also includes this **NamingContextFactory**

**EDIT:**

It is the mix of these two dependencies that unfortunately are inherited from required dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.naming</groupId>
        <artifactId>jnp-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and spring-webmvc inside

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

If I run with

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
 </dependency>
```

It works fine.

Now, if I exclude the jnp-client I cannot access the JNDI resource, but if I remove the spring-security-web I cannot access the REST endopoints this service exposes.

**EDIT2:**

So I thought it could be two classes interfering with each other and I started the java process with -verbose. This is what I found.

> org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader$$Lambda$165/0x00000001002d8440
> source:
> org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader
> [389.020s][info][class,load]
> org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader$$Lambda$166/0x00000001002d8840
> source:
> org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader
> [558.011s][info][class,load]
> org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader$$Lambda$167/0x00000001002d8c40
> source:
> org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader
> [558.012s][info][class,load]
> org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader$$Lambda$168/0x00000001002d9040
> source:
> org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader

From time to time the application prints, only in verbose, this **ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader**

**EDIT 3:**

It seems that the problem is TimedSocketFactory inside the jnp-client. Somehow, just by having this class inside the jnp-client dependency, the Spring application is blocked and never starts. Removing this from the jnp-client allows the application to start. Of course, it fails later because the JNDI cannot connect to the server.

Comment: Could you post your complete maven configuration?

Comment: Hi Marbrey, thanks for reading my post and asking about it. I could post the whole 'effective' pom.xml, however, I found out that the problem comes from mixing the two dependencies that I included in my edit.

Comment: Hey Daniel, the spring-boot-starter-web dependency looks kinda odd to me. Shouldn't it be `<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>` ? I coudn't find a package in the maven repo with this groupId and artifactId. Also I am missing a `<version>`-tag.

Comment: Er... true, sorry. Wrong copy paste. I fix it now.